# how to set Pandas to extract certain rows of certain columns and stack them on top of each other?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How can I extract certain columns and rows to stack them together?

I created a simple exemplary dataframe with this data:

```
data = {'d1':[101,201,301,401],
        'd2':[102,202,302,402],
        'd3':[103,203,303,403],
        'd4':[104,204,304,404]
        }

dfa = pd.DataFrame(data, index=['t1','t2','t3','t4'])
dfa
     d1   d2   d3   d4
t1  101  102  103  104
t2  201  202  203  204
t3  301  302  303  304
t4  401  402  403  404
```

This is what I would like to get:

```
   d1_d2_d3-t1-t2
1             101
2             201
3             102
4             202
5             103
6             203
```

Another Format I would like to get is in two columns:

```
   d1_d2_d3-t1-t2  d1_d2_d3-t3-t4
1             101             301
2             201             401
3             102             302
4             202             402
5             103             303
6             203             403
```

The headers in the desired results are just for explanation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) for filtering with [`DataFrame.melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) for reshape:

```
idx = ['t1','t2']
cols = ['d1','d2', 'd3']
df = dfa.loc[idx, cols].melt(value_name='data')[['data']]
```

Another solution is convert values to numpy array, flatten by [`numpy.ravel`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ravel.html) and create new DataFrame by constructor:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'data': dfa.loc[idx, cols].values.ravel()})
```

---

```
print (df)
   data
0   101
1   201
2   102
3   202
4   103
5   203

idx1 = ['t1','t2']
idx2 = ['t3','t4']
cols = ['d1','d2', 'd3']
df = pd.concat([dfa.loc[idx1, cols].melt(value_name='data1')[['data1']],
                dfa.loc[idx2, cols].melt(value_name='data2')[['data2']]], axis=1)
```

Or:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'data1': dfa.loc[idx1, cols].values.ravel(),
                   'data2': dfa.loc[idx2, cols].values.ravel()})
```

---

```
print (df)
   data1  data2
0    101    301
1    201    401
2    102    302
3    202    402
4    103    303
5    203    403
```